# beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError:RuntimeValueProvider(option: output_path, type: str, default_value: None).get() not called from a runtime context

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

i'm experiencing error when trying to run Run value provider in dataflow pubsub to gcs job.

```
import argparse
import logging
import random
from datetime import datetime

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import DoFn, GroupByKey, io, ParDo, Pipeline, PTransform, WindowInto, WithKeys
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.window import FixedWindows

class CustomPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            "--output_path",
            type=str,
            help="Path of the output GCS file including the prefix.",
        )

class WriteToGCS(DoFn):
    def __init__(self, output_path):
        self.output_path = output_path

    def process(self, key_value, window=DoFn.WindowParam):
        """Write messages in a batch to Google Cloud Storage."""

        ts_format = "%H:%M"
        window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
        window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
        shard_id, batch = key_value
        seq = self.output_path, window_start, window_end, str(shard_id)
        filename = "-".join(seq)

        with io.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filename=filename, mode="w") as f:
            for message_body in batch:
                f.write("{}\n".format(message_body).encode("utf-8"))

def run(input_topic, num_shards, window_size):


    # Set `save_main_session` to True so DoFns can access globally imported modules.
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )

    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(CustomPipelineOptions)
    
    output_path = custom_options.output_path.get()
    
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic)
            | "Write to GCS" >> ParDo(WriteToGCS(custom_options.output_path))
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument(
            "--input_topic",
            help="The Cloud Pub/Sub topic to read from."
            '"projects/<PROJECT_ID>/topics/<TOPIC_ID>".',
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--num_shards",
            default=5,
            type=int,
            help="Number of shards to use when writing windowed elements to GCS.",
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--window_size",
            default=1,
            type=int,
            help="Output file's window size in minutes.",
        )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run(
        known_args.input_topic,
        known_args.num_shards,
        known_args.window_size
        )
```

The error trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "first.py", line 107, in <module> known_args.window_size 
File "first.py", line 68, in run output_path = custom_options.output_path.get() 
File "/home/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 125, in get '%s.get() not called from a runtime context' % self) 
apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: output_path, type: str, default_value: None).get() not called from a runtime context
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you edit your post and add the full error message?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 107, in <module>
    known_args.window_size
  File "first.py", line 68, in run
    output_path = custom_options.output_path.get()
  File "/home/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 125, in get
    '%s.get() not called from a runtime context' % self)
apache_beam.error.RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: output_path, type: str, default_value: None).get() not called from a runtime context

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `output_path = custom_options.output_path.get()`, as pointed out by the traceback.

You can't access a runtime value provider at that point, because that is at pipeline construction time. You can only access it at pipeline runtime (i.e. within your `WriteToGCS` class).

Remove that line, and make sure that you call get on `RuntimeValueProvider`s only in pipeline runtime functions (e.g. inside your DoFn).

Comment: when i tried this I'm getting different error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67625087/attributeerror-dofnparam-object-has-no-attribute-start-while-running-wri