# AttributeError: '_DoFnParam' object has no attribute 'start' [while running 'Write to GCS-ptransform-146']

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

> When I run Beam program i'm getting below error.

```
2021-05-20T17:04:42.166994441ZError message from worker: generic::unknown: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 762, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 887, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window 
File "first.py", line 68, in process AttributeError: '_DoFnParam' object has no attribute 'start' 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 289, in _execute response = task() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 362, in <lambda> lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 607, in do_instruction getattr(request, request_type), request.instruction_id) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 644, in process_bundle bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1001, in process_bundle element.data) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 229, in process_encoded self.output(decoded_value) 
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 356, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output 
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 358, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output 
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 220, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive 
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 717, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process 
File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 718, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1235, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1315, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 446, in raise_with_traceback raise exc.with_traceback(traceback) 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1233, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 762, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker.invoke_process 
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 887, in apache_beam.runners.common.PerWindowInvoker._invoke_process_per_window 
File "first.py", line 68, in process AttributeError: '_DoFnParam' object has no attribute 'start' [while running 'Write to GCS-ptransform-146']
```

Code:

```
import argparse
import logging
import random
from datetime import datetime

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import DoFn, GroupByKey, io, ParDo, Pipeline, PTransform, WindowInto, WithKeys
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.window import FixedWindows

class CustomPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            "--output_path",
            type=str,
            help="Path of the output GCS file including the prefix.",
        )
class WriteToGCS(DoFn):
    def __init__(self, output_path):
        self.output_path = output_path
    def process(self, custom_options, output_path, window=DoFn.WindowParam):
        """Write messages in a batch to Google Cloud Storage."""

        ts_format = "%H:%M"
        window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
        window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format)
        output_path = custom_options.output_path.get()
        filename = "-".join([output_path, window_start, window_end, str(shard_id)])

        with io.gcsio.GcsIO().open(filename=filename, mode="w") as f:
            for message_body in batch:
                f.write("{}\n".format(message_body).encode("utf-8"))

def run(input_topic, num_shards, window_size):

    global custom_options
    # Set `save_main_session` to True so DoFns can access globally imported modules.
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        pipeline_args, streaming=True, save_main_session=True
    )

    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(CustomPipelineOptions)
    
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        (
            pipeline
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic)
            | "Write to GCS" >> ParDo(WriteToGCS(custom_options.output_path))
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument(
            "--input_topic",
            help="The Cloud Pub/Sub topic to read from."
            '"projects/<PROJECT_ID>/topics/<TOPIC_ID>".',
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--num_shards",
            default=5,
            type=int,
            help="Number of shards to use when writing windowed elements to GCS.",
        )
    parser.add_argument(
            "--window_size",
            default=1,
            type=int,
            help="Output file's window size in minutes.",
        )
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run(
        known_args.input_topic,
        known_args.num_shards,
        known_args.window_size
        )
```

Comment: This happens, proably, when you call `window.start` in your process function. Can you log the value of `window` to see what it is? It probably is just the GlobalWindow?

Comment: Window: WindowParam is the value. For window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime().strftime(ts_format) It is genrating the error.

Comment: that's clear. Did you try logging the value of `window`?

Answer (score 0):

In your WriteToGCS DoFn, you declared in the process method that the DoFn will take arg `custom_options` and `output_path`, however the they do not have default values and it seems the parameter translation will map the WindowParam onto the wrong arg.

you'll need to remove the unused parameters from the process method to make the DoFn parameter translation correct, additional parameters can be passed and retrieved from `**kwargs` in process fn.